# How to change the style of the Facebook share button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I know this question has been asked before, but the answer is either outdated (talking about iframes), wrong (not allowed to change it), or confusing.

Once and for all, how do you change the style of the Facebook share button?

Pasting their code into my site produces some ugly looking thing of the wrong size and in the wrong language.

**I want it to look like the other buttons on my site, and I want the text on it to be what I say it should be.** Even if it can't be the exact text I use, it should at least be in the right language, like the Twitter button.

Browsing the dev guide on Facebook's site I found the following quote:

> If your website doesn't need a button to open share dialog or **Facebook
>   provided button doesn't fit into your website design**, Web Share Dialog
>   is also provided for sharing links.

However, the Web Share Dialog is *the* most confusing thing I've ever read about. It gives zero actual guidance and comes with a bunch of confusing statements.

> The Share dialog gives people the ability to publish an individual
>   story to their timeline, a friend's timeline, a group, or in a private
>   message on Messenger. This does not require Facebook Login or any
>   extended permissions, so it is the easiest way to enable sharing on
>   the web.

What? People without Facebook accounts can share things on their timeline? They don't even have a timeline...

> Trigger a Share Dialog using the FB.ui function with the share method
>   parameter to share a link.

I have no idea what it is and they don't explain it.

This goes on and on, and I literally understand NOTHING and I'm not some stupid Wordpress blogger.

**Can someone please explain how to go about doing this since Facebook refuses to?**

**Edit:** I've gotten as far as using the Facebook Javascript SKD now, but it requests an `app_id`.

Their page says that an `app_id` is:

> Your app's unique identifier. Required.

But I'm not making an app. I'm making a webpage...

Comment: Can you show your current design for the social buttons? I can sort it out, and will explain each quote you posted.

Comment: @AdamAzad Not sure, but the official Tweet button looks alright and I guess it's equally as complicated to change so I might as well go with that style. Otherwise, I would use the button layout of Semantic UI (http://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html). Don't need a complete style guide, just how get things changed in the first place!

Comment: "isn´t working" is not a sufficient error/problem description. as a developer, the first thing to do is open the browser console. any error/warning there? do you have a test link?

Comment: @luschn That wasn't my problem description. The error is below the code.

Comment: i don´t see any error message

Comment: "Of course, it doesn't what FB is because how could it?" - that does not make any sense. please explain.

Comment: ok, finally you added the message. did you try this locally by any chance? without any webserver? did you open your code locally without a server on localhost?

Comment: @luschn Yes. But I guess I should know that that doesn't work, right? Definitely not in the docs.

Comment: yes, you should know. but not because of the facebook docs, because it´s very basic stuff you should know as web developer. why should they add that kind of information to the docs? try it on a real server, or add "https" to the js sdk url.

Comment: @luschn Mmm, yes very basic stuff indeed, except it's literally restricted to Facebook stuff.

Comment: if you omit http/https, it will use the protocol of the page. if you just open the html page in your browser without a server, there is no http/https. that´s not at all related to facebook and it´s very common to omit the protocol (NOT just with the facebook stuff).

Comment: so how exactly is that restricted to facebook stuff?

Comment: @luschn Because it works with, for instance, Twitter share buttons.

Comment: so? twitter may just NOT omit the protocol. but in general, it´s better to omit it. it´s really not a "social media" related issue, it´s web development basics. anyway, this is completely off topic already, the answers to your questions are in my answer already.

Comment: btw, i edited my answer a last time, take a look at the "2 options". just use "sharer.php" if you don´t want to deal with apps and the js sdk.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, ignore people who say you can't change the layout of Facebook's share button. It is allowed and a lot of sites do it.

Also, ignore the docs because they are useless and will only confuse you. Their code snippets are wrong, and so is their FAQ.

Despite Facebook's docs claiming otherwise, you absolutely need to create a "Facebook App", which is like an developer/admin page where you can edit some settings (and give Facebook your phone number).

Then you need to initialize the JavaScript SDK on your page (don't forget to add your actual app id from your Javascript App page into the `appId`):

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-app-id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And then you can use whatever button you want, like this:

```
<button class="ui facebook button">Share</button>
```

To get it do something when you click on it, use regular JS or jQuery event listener:

```
<script>
    $(".ui.facebook.button").click(function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'share',
            href: 'your-webpage.html',
}, function(response){});
    })
</script>
```

This will only work on the correct webpage, not locally.

Then you need to make the share page show the correct image and text. This is a different topic and it can range from easy to quite annoying depending on what platform you're working with. Search for instructions that fit your case.

Comment: There _is_ not default style in this case – _because_ you just call the dialog from within your own code, however you like – it can be a button, an image, a link … it is totally up to you.

Comment: The default style: their default button that I wanted to get away from. Read the question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100658/discussion-on-answer-by-yeats-how-to-change-the-style-of-the-facebook-share-butt).

Comment: Is this solution factible if i want this for a dynamic pages? like href: your_webpage.html will always change so i can't put static url on the JS code or jQuery. How can i make it so?

Answer (score 9):

You are not allowed to change the appearance of Social Plugins in any way, but you can use your own image with the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) or the `sharer.php` link. For the second option, you don´t even need an App ID, just open a link with the urlencoded URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[urlencoded-url]
```

About the Share Dialog: They say "This does not require Facebook Login", which does not mean "you don´t need a Facebook account". Those are completely different things. "Facebook Login" means "authorization in your App" in that case. You need to read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

The docs are really good nowadays, but you should take your time reading all of it, not just the parts you need right now: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

**In other words, you have 2 options:**

- Use Social Plugins - NOT allowed to change the appearance, except for the official settings
- Create your own Share Button graphics and use the Share Dialog or sharer.php. For the Share Dialog, you need to include the JavaScript SDK (because it is based on that one) and create an App. For the sharer.php, you really just need to open the link.

About the language of the Share Button: You can set a language with the JS SDK easily, check out this article: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/ - there is this line, with the language:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

Btw, very important information about using/changing Facebook graphics: https://www.facebookbrand.com/dos-donts

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100659/discussion-on-answer-by-luschn-how-to-change-the-style-of-the-facebook-share-but).

Answer (score -3):

It is possible to overwrite the CSS styles of the buttons, which is still a valid approach. Just look up the CSS classes that Facebook is using and override them with your preferences.

Make sure that your custom styles follow the default FB styles.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/